# Remove Nulls From Query Builder Laravel

Tags: laravel, lumen

Im having a little trouble with some return data that I'm getting when running a **Query Builder** then paginating the data

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could remove Null Results before I paginate the data.

```
    // So Before I hit this
    $return = $tld->paginate($request->get('limit'))->toArray();
```

This is the issue after I paginate

```
array:12 [
  "current_page" => 1
  "data" => array:12 [
    0 => null
    1 => array:3 [
```

I need to get rid of those Null values, I know how to do it after I paginate however I want to get rid of them before I paginate...

Im hoping that some of you laravel Gods can help me ..

Added this extra logic for $tld

```
private function newest(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'timescale' => [
            'required',
            Rule::in(['today', 'this_week', 'this_month', 'all_time'])
        ]
    ]);

    $tld = TimelineItem::where('timeline_items.created_at', '>', $this->timescaleToHours($request->get('timescale')));

    if ($request->search_content) {
        $tld = $this->searchContent($tld, $request->search_content, 0.4);
    } else {
        $tld = $tld->orderBy('timeline_items.created_at', 'DESC');
    }

    if ($request->types) {
        $tld = $this->filters($tld, $request->types);
    }

    if ($request->tags) {
        $tld = $this->tags($tld, $request->tags);
    }

    return $tld;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide whole query for pagination?

Comment: Is this what you are after 

select * from `timeline_items` left join `users` on `timeline_items`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `timeline_items`.`created_at` > ? and `users`.`website_id` in (?, ?) order by `timeline_items`.`created_at` desc"

Comment: What is the meaning of $tld variable? Please provide whole model structure of $tld.

Comment: Ive added it above ^ this is someone elses code that im working on so just a little confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **filter()** to remove null. [Laravel Collection filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-filter)

```
$response = $tld->paginate($request->get('limit'))->toArray();
$response['data'] = collect($response['data'])->filter()->toArray();
return $response;
```

Comment: I tried that but got this error "message": "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::filter()",

Comment: use `->get()->filter()`. Updated my answer.

Comment: O no not another error message is this because the get is turning it into a collection 

"message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::paginate does not exist.",

Comment: Third times the charm, I guess. Check the response now.

Comment: Nooooooo why does something so easy seem so complicated ahah...

"message": "Call to a member function filter() on null",

Comment: We will get this done. What's the response of `$tld->paginate($request->get('limit'));`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217146/discussion-between-digvijay-and-bob-hiller).

Comment: it changes the structure of data. this doesnt solve my problem